# Trying to find a children's book series from the 1980s

Tags: story-identification, books

In the mid-1980s I read a series of books (possibly a trilogy) aimed at the 9+ age bracket. I don't remember much about the story except that it was set in a distant galaxy (no Earth references), and the hero was on an epic quest to save the galaxy.

It was a real space opera with spaceships and alien planets and the books covers were wild alien vistas like something from '70s fantasy art. I think one had some kind of enormous alien skyscraper-like building on it.

It was published in hardback in the UK circa 1984. I got all three books from the school book club leaflet (the Chip Book Club, possibly). I have a vague sense that it was published by Harper Collins (this could be BS).

It definitely wasn't the *Starstormers* series.

Sorry to be so vague. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Was it something like Star Kings by Edmond Hamilton?

Comment: It wasn't Star Kings, but thank you for the suggestion. Was definitely published in hardback in the mid-1980s in the UK

Comment: I meant overall style of the book. And it would be nice if you can provide some parts of the plot, some name, may be FTL engines, weapons, etc.

Comment: Maybe the Isis trilogy by Monica Hughes? 1. The Keeper of the Isis Light, 2. The Guardian of Isis, 3. The Isis Pedlar. It possibly fits because it's a trilogy, published in the UK in the 1980s, with a ten-year-old protagonist on a planet far from Earth. https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1190250.The_Keeper_of_the_Isis_Light

Comment: Or, possibly, the Last Legionary series by Douglas Hill. The Wikipedia description of the series pegs it firmly as space opera, and the plot description isn't too far off yours. It's in the right time-frame, and it had UK hardcovers in the early 1980s. The cover of the third book (Day of the Starwind) has a skyscraper-type building. Check ISFDB and look for the Gollancz editions to see the UK hardcovers.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Legionary
http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?337462
http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?6248

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be *The Last Legionary* series, written by Canadian author Douglas Hill.  The main four-volume series (*Galactic Warlord*, *Deathwing Over Veynaa*, *Day of the Starwind*, and *Planet of the Warlord*) was published from 1979 to 1981 (with a much lower quality prequel, *Young Legionary* in 1982).

The series is a classic of space opera for children.  The protagonist—the eponymous last Legionary, Kiell Randor—travels from planet to planet, battling agents of the titular Warlord, who is slowly plotting to take over the galaxy.  The galaxy in the series is actually our own, but there the home planet of Earth is not mentioned anywhere, human civilization having spread all across the stars through the use of Overlight travel.

In *Galactic Warlord*, the entire population of Kiell's home planet of Moros is wiped out by a radiation bomb, planted by members of Deathwing, the Warlord's group of elite agents.  The people who had originally colonized Moros, which was practically a death world, had grown to become extremely tough or resilient, and they eventually formed the galaxy's most elite mercenary corps, the Legions of Moros, who posed an obvious danger to the Warlord's plans.  Kiell, whose battle group was away from Moros at the time of the attack, receives only a limited dose of the deadly radiation when he returns to Moros's star system—enough to kill him, but only slowly.

As he searches for more survivors, as well as information about who killed his people, Kiell is kidnapped by a group of reclusive scientists who have also come to realize the danger the Warlord poses, although they still know very little about the Warlord; the Warlord's actual identity is unknown until the fourth book, and the Warlord's long-term plans for galactic domination are only inferred.  The scientists, with the help of a flying, telepathic, extragalactic alien named Glyr, kidnap Kiel and completely replace his irradiated bones with a synthetic skeleton—saving his life and giving him a skeleton that is effectively unbreakable under normal circumstances.  As he heals, they brief him about what they do know about the Warlord, then dispatch him and the alien Glyr to investigate and try to thwart the Warlord's future endeavors.

The third book, *Day of the Starwind*, specifically features of tower as an important thematic element, and the tower was shown on most versions of the book cover.  If you read the books in the early to mid-1980s in hardback, you may well have seen the original cover, the first one shown below.

[image: Original Cover]

[image: Piccolo Edition]

[image: Weird Cover]

(What is the Millennium Falcon doing on this one?)

[image: One More Cover]

[image: Recent Cover]

There is also one more commonly seen cover, which I have not posted, because it does not obviously show the Deathwing tower, and it actually shows a major spoiler.

[*Day of the Starwind*](https://archive.org/details/dayofstarwind00hill) and [*Planet of the Warlord*](https://archive.org/details/planetofwarlord0000hill) (but not seemingly the first two books) can be checked out for free from archive.org.

The *Last Legionary* books have also be a frequent target for [story-identification](/questions/tagged/story-identification) questions:

- [SciFi series from the 80s (or 70s?): main character with bionic powers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/30561/scifi-series-from-the-80s-or-70s-main-character-with-bionic-powers)
- [Help identifying book about a supersoldier with a twist ending](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103152/help-identifying-book-about-a-supersoldier-with-a-twist-ending) (This one is specifically about the second book, *Deathwing Over Veynaa*, the original hardcover jacket of which also showed a striking, alien, tower-like building.)

[image: Deathwing Over Veynaa Original Cover]

- [Dying person is the last in his race of warriors, trying to find the people who killed his race](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87144/dying-person-is-the-last-in-his-race-of-warriors-trying-to-find-the-people-who)
- [World of 'police' killed, one saved and pursues perpetrators](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161961/world-of-police-killed-one-saved-and-pursues-perpetrators)
- [Humankind colonizes planets, main character is a "spartan" with augmented bones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/30672/humankind-colonizes-planets-main-character-is-a-spartan-with-augmented-bones)
- [Mystery book series with an alien bird side-kick and a Protagonist called something like Jarrod](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/173563/mystery-book-series-with-an-alien-bird-side-kick-and-a-protagonist-called-someth)
- [1980s/90s science fiction book. Hero gets trapped in high tech straightjacket](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149632/1980s-90s-science-fiction-book-hero-gets-trapped-in-high-tech-straightjacket)
- [Young-adult science fiction novel series. Kid trained as warrior, all other kid warriors wiped out](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/63155/young-adult-science-fiction-novel-series-kid-trained-as-warrior-all-other-kid)
- [Young adult science fiction book from the early 80s: alien race adept at martial arts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/234287/young-adult-science-fiction-book-from-the-early-80s-alien-race-adept-at-martial)
- [Space opera featuring gladiatorial combat with an enhanced main character](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/241444/space-opera-featuring-gladiatorial-combat-with-an-enhanced-main-character)
- [Book (pre 1982) - recalled mercenary only survivor of radiation weapon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67493/book-pre-1982-recalled-mercenary-only-survivor-of-radiation-weapon)
- [series of young adult science fiction books from early 1980s about last of a race of martial experts that sees the destruction of his home planet](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47022/series-of-young-adult-science-fiction-books-from-early-1980s-about-last-of-a-rac)
- [Identify book about fighting tournament with the opponent wearing gold armor, plus rulers being mind-controlled by tentacled being](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8499/identify-book-about-fighting-tournament-with-the-opponent-wearing-gold-armor-pl)
- [Scifi book from the 80's. The last of a warrior race](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/65329/scifi-book-from-the-80s-the-last-of-a-warrior-race)
- [Freedom fighter versus evil space empire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/195338/freedom-fighter-versus-evil-space-empire)
- [Need help identifying this 'space novel'](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51763/need-help-identifying-this-space-novel)

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! The Last Legionary was definitely the series I was thinking of. I'm thrilled to rediscover it. It was such a huge influence on me as a kid, opening the gateway to Clarke and Asimov and Gibson and more... Really grateful to you all :)